# D3.js Pointer Coordinates relative to the axis Domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using d3.js and the d3.pointer class, I am recieving the SVG coordinates for pointermove events. I'm struggling to relate these coordinates to meaningful numbers on the linear axes when the axes do not start from 0 (or may go negative).

`

```
function pointermoved(d) {
    const [x, y] = d3.pointer(d);
    document.getElementById("X-COORDINATES").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("Y-COORDINATES").innerHTML = y;
}
```

`

How do a relate these to the drawn axes domains?

Comment: What version of d3 are you using?